# Scrapy/Django - PyCharm debugger - can't import model

Tags: python, django, scrapy, pycharm

I have a spider that scrapes websites based on Django model Domain. I created a custom configuration for scrapy to be able to use PyCharm Debugger.

The problem is that when I run spider using Debugger, it raises this error:

```
from core.models import Domain
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.models'
```

But when I run it this way:

```
scrapy crawl domain_spider
```

it works correctly.

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import timedelta

import django
import scrapy

from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Spider



DJANGO_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
sys.path.append(DJANGO_DIR)
print(DJANGO_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mspiders.settings'
django.setup()
from core.models import Domain
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.timezone import now


class DomainSpider(Spider):
    name = 'domain_spider'
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36",
        'LOG_FILE': 'logs/domain_spider.log',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 100,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 20,
        'DNS_TIMEOUT': 20,
        'RETRY_TIMES': 2,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
```

The `sys.path.append(DJANGO_DIR)` line prints this:

```
'/home/milano/PycharmProjects/spiders/mspiders'
```

which is a correct Django project directory

This is a configuration:

[image]

This is very weird since I use such a configuration often without any problems.